# How can i take away 2 values from a .txt file

Tags: python, csv

```
 if "A" in columns and int(columns[5]) < int(columns[3]):
            print(columns)
            print (columns[3]) - (columns[5])
```

What have I done wrong here? Bare in mind I recently started coding.

This is the full code:

```
import csv

FILE_NAME = "paintingJobs.txt" #I use this so that the file can be used easier
COL_HEADERS = ['Number', 'Date', 'ID', 'Total', 'Status', 'Paid']
NUM_COLS = len(COL_HEADERS)#This will insure that the header of each column fits into the length of the data

# read file once to determine maximum width of data in columns
with open(FILE_NAME) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    # determine the maximum width of the data in each column
    max_col_widths = [len(col_header) for col_header in COL_HEADERS]
    for columns in reader:
        for i, col in enumerate(columns):
            if "A" in columns and int(columns[5]) < int(columns[3]):
                max_col_widths[i] = max(max_col_widths[i], len(repr(col)))
    # add 1 to each for commas
    max_col_widths = [col_width+1 for col_width in max_col_widths]

# read file second time to display its contents with the headers
with open(FILE_NAME) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    # display justified column headers
    print(' ' + ' '.join(col_header.ljust(max_col_widths[i])
                            for i, col_header in enumerate(COL_HEADERS)))
    # display justified column data
    for columns in reader:
        if "A" in columns and int(columns[5]) < int(columns[3]):
            print(columns)
            print (columns[3]) - (columns[5])`
```

And this is the error I get:

```
line 72, in Option_B
print (columns[3]) - (columns[5])
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: Post your example input, output, what you have tried and what results you expect.

Comment: Are you getting an error message, if so, what?  Are you getting an incorrect result?  What is columns?  What result did you expect?  Are you using Python 2?

Comment: Ok I have updated the post

Comment: Can you post the full error message? Meaning, also the information in which line the error occurs.

Comment: the error message makes it pretty clear that `columns[3]` is `None` and `columns[5]` is a string.  you are attempting to subtract the latter from the former.  that makes no sense.  correct this.

Comment: there's also no reason to keep the file open while you print things you've already read out of the file.

Comment: I can't seem to find out how to, do you have a solution for the error?

Comment: What happens if you convert the columns to `int` as you do in your `if` statement? I.e. `print int(column[3]) - int(column[5])`.

Comment: I get a syntax error

Comment: Well you should probably use parenthesis as well: `print(int(column[3]) - int(column[5]))`

Comment: Thanks that has worked, is there any way of labeling each outcome as Total Outstanding?

Comment: @NigelHarrison If you use the @ tag next time I will be properly notified when you write. See my answer below.

Comment: @pingul Ok thank you

Comment: @NigelHarrison Also, if the answer helped you solve the problem, please accept the answer so others know as well. If the issue was something else you can post your own answer to the question and accept that one.

Comment: @pingul Now I have printed out the Total amount on each one is there a way to add each total amount up to a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably convert your numbers before you print:

```
print("The result: ")
print(int(column[3]) - int(column[5]))
```